# Replace one URL with another without regex

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace some URLs in a database (wordpress) with another, but it's tricky because a lot of the URLs are redirects. I'm trying to either replace the URL with the redirected URL, or with a URL of my choosing, based on the result. I can get the matching done without any problems, but I can't replace it. I've tried str_replace, but it doesn't seem to replace the URLs. When I try preg_replace, it will give "Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash". Can anyone point me in the right way to do this?

```
if(preg_match($url_regex,$row['post_content'])){
    preg_match_all($url_regex,$row['post_content'],$matches);

    foreach($matches[0] as $match){
        echo "{$row['ID']} \t{$row['post_date']} \t{$row['post_title']}\t{$row['guid']}";

        $newUrl = NULL;
        if(stripos($url_regex,'domain1') !== false || stripos($url_regex,'domain2') !== false || stripos($url_regex,'domain3') !== false){
            $match = str_replace('&amp;','&',$match);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$match);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            $html = curl_exec($ch);
            $newUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

            if(stripos($newUrl,'domain4') !== false)
                $newUrl = NULL;

        }
        else

        if($newUrl == NULL)
        {   $newUrl = 'http://www.mysite.com/';

        }
        echo "\t$match\t$newUrl";
        $content = str_replace($match,$newUrl,$row['post_content']); 
        echo "\t (" . strlen($content).")";
        echo "\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: re error: "Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" - show us the regex.  Sounds like you are just missing // [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) around your expression.

Comment: The preg_replace error comes if I use it instead of str_replace near the bottom.  preg_replace($match,$newUrl,$row['post_content']);

Comment: why can't you use regex to do the replacement?  In question, but no explanation in text.

Comment: @aynber: `var_dump($match);`  Does the expression have delimiters? i.e. good -> `/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/`, bad -> `(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)`

Comment: The initial regex ($url_regex) checks for the domain name. Domains 1, 2, and 3 are all redirect domains. There may be several redirect URLs in each post, but they don't all point to the same URL.

Comment: @ficuscr No, $match is a straight URL. Unless there's a way to convert a string to a regex.

Comment: hmm, RTFM -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php  The error you get is no mystery.  Also `str_replace` would also work just fine if your needle was in the haystack.  These functions are not buggy, you just need to know how to use them.

Comment: No, the error I get is no mystery, it's how to solve it. str_replace doesn't replace it These aren't straight domains, they have variables. $match is usually something like http://www.domain.com/app/adtrack.asp?mID=12345&aID=12345.

Comment: Another example is http://click.domain2.com/ClickThru.aspx?pubids=7889%7c60932%7c78923%7c87998&amp;digest=DDOnH6T%2fdWaLy3zr6z6Z4A&amp;sysid=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do it with Perl Regular Expressions.

```
$baesUrlMappings = array('/www.yoursite.com/i' => 'www.mysite.com', 
                         '/www.yoursite2.com/i' => 'www.mysite2.com',);

echo preg_replace(array_keys($baesUrlMappings), array_values($baesUrlMappings), 'http://www.yoursite.com/foo/bar?id=123');
echo preg_replace(array_keys($baesUrlMappings), array_values($baesUrlMappings), 'http://www.yoursite2.com/foo/bar?id=123');
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/2ne7u6

Please read the manual!  You should be able to figure this out.

Comment: Alas, if you can't respond to the error yourself, post the error, read a manual, or otherwise provide useful information it makes it pretty tough to help you.  ESP tells me its probably you needing to escape the string for use in the regex pattern...

Comment: Sorry, I was playing with the code on that page. With a / delimiter, it gave "Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/'". Which, of course, it would with all the /'s in the URL. With an @ delimiter, I didn't get an error, but it also didn't replace the URL.

Comment: If I put it together with preg_quote(), it worked. And it also helped if I always used the most recent edit of the post... *facepalm* Thanks for the dialogue, your suggestions and talking it out helped!

Comment: Cool.  Was gonna propose a chat soon otherwise.  Glad you got it sorted.